# Is there any way to create multiple files at the same time using NERDTree?

Tags: vim, nerdtree

I know that you can use `m` and then `a` to add a child node in NERDTree to add files or directories one at a time.  Is there anyway to type out a list, e.g. `{Book,Author}.php` and get a corresponding file or directory for each one in the list?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If on Bash Shell, I would do this in Vim `command mode`:

```
q:i!touch  {Book,Author}.php
```

- **q:i** -- Enter into Vim command history window (**q:**), then insert (**i**), it also let you edit commands with all Vim's editing power.
- **!** -- To use shell
- **touch mydir/{my_file_1,my_file_2}.php -- This will create the empty files.
- actually, do it in Bash Shell will be simpler.

Comment: I don't know how you found my question months later but thank you very much!